# Cannot bind object method inside it via IIFE

Tags: javascript, this, apply, bind

Cannot figure out why `bind` is not working with `IIFE` inside object method? What I've missed?

Thanks in advance.

Example:

```js
var a = {
  b: () => console.log('Hello'),
  c: (() => this.b()).bind(a)()
}

a.b()
a.c
```

```
// Error: Uncaught TypeError: this.b is not a function
```

Comment: There is no answer inside the recommended post. Please, I really need an explanation why...

Comment: Thanks. I read, btw there is no explanation correspond to my problem. FYI

Comment: You're trying to reference the `b` property in the object initializer, which doesn't work because the object hasn't been initialized yet. You're also referencing `this.b` in an attempt to get to the `b` property, but arrow functions inherit the `this` from their outer scope

Comment: @CertainPerformance I've tried such a way because of the `c: (() => this.b())()` does not work (where we expect that arrow func will grab local `this` context by itself, but it's not happen).